# Error on searching for OwnerId

Tags: error, search

I'm getting an error while filtering the search by OwnerId for Task object.

Following is what i'm doing and it is giving me an error :  Error: Compile Error: expecting a semi-colon, found ' and OwnerId in :ownerIds' at line 106 column 142

```
   public void  queryTasks(){

    String qStr2= searchText;
    Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
    String strnormal = '';
    try{
         mydate = date.parse(qStr2);
    }catch(Exception e)
    { }

    String strDate = '';
    if(mydate != null) {
     // strnormal = String.valueOf(mydate );
      String[] qstr3 = String.valueOf(mydate).split(' ',2); 
      strDate = ' ActivityDate =  '+ qstr3[0] + ' ';
    }else{

       strDate  =  'Subject like \'%'+searchText +'%\' OR Status like \'%' +searchText+ '%\' Order By '  + sortField;
    }

    if (ownerIds != null && ownerIds.size() > 0){

      String qStr = 'Select OwnerId,Subject,Status,ActivityDate from Task where '+strDate+' limit ' + QueryLimit + ' offset ' + OffsetSize' and OwnerId in :ownerIds';

     }

        //String qStr ='Select OwnerId,Subject,Status,ActivityDate from Task where \''+strDate +'\' limit ' + QueryLimit + ' offset ' + OffsetSize;
        // String qStr = 'Select OwnerId,Subject,Status,ActivityDate from Task where '+strDate+' limit ' + QueryLimit + ' offset ' + OffsetSize;


       System.debug(qStr);

        //  String qStr = 'Select OwnerId,Subject,Status,Priority from Task where Subject like \'%'+searchText+'%\' OR Status like \'%'+searchText+ '%\' Order By ' + sortField;


       tasks = Database.query(qStr);
        //tasks.sort();

     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing a + between OffsetSize' and the rest of the statement:

```
  String qStr = 'Select OwnerId,Subject,Status,ActivityDate from Task where '+strDate+' limit ' + QueryLimit + ' offset ' + OffsetSize' and OwnerId in :ownerIds';
```

It should be

```
  String qStr = 'Select OwnerId,Subject,Status,ActivityDate from Task where '+strDate+' limit ' + QueryLimit + ' offset ' + OffsetSize + ' and OwnerId in :ownerIds';
```

Comment: Just want to cross check that i'm mentioning my IF condition for OwnerId after ELSE part of date . This is because i'm getting error for qStr not defined whereas i've already defined .

Comment: @james, yeah thats because you create it with the if() and the try to access it outside the if()....if you declare a variable within an if, you can't access it outside. Read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science) and then do 50 pushups :)

Comment: i'd already mentioned that in If but still the same. Anyways,good learning from you.